# Radio button selection on jquery tabs label click

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, radio-button

I had a simple working (ASP.NET) Scenario here:
3 asp:RadioButtons that  each have OnCheckedChanged event that will update an asp:gridview.

But now, I want to put some description for each radiobutton selection,and I thought it would be a good idea to embed them in JQuery UI Tabs like the following :

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1"> 
       <asp:RadioButton  ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="option1"  Checked="True"
        AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" /> </a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">
       <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="option2"
        AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">
       <asp:RadioButton  ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text="option3"
       AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" /></a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1"> <p>  content1</p>   </div>
 <div id="tabs-2"> <p>  content2</p>   </div>
 <div id="tabs-3"> <p>  content3</p>   </div>
 </div>
```

and the jquery is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

I want the corresponding radiobuttons for each tabs be selected after switching to that tab (by clicking anywhere inside that tab)
I don't know how to that probably by JQuery or JavaScript or any other kind suggestion.
Please help me

Generated HTML source :

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">
                            <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="RadioButtonCart" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$g2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButtonCart"/><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButtonCart">option1</label></a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-2">
                            <span style="color: Green;"><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$RadioButtonShetab\',\'\')', 0)" value="RadioButtonShetab" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$g2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButtonShetab"/><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButtonShetab">option2</label></span></a></li>
                        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-3">
                            <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$RadioButtonFish\',\'\')', 0)" value="RadioButtonFish" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$g2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButtonFish"/><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButtonFish">option3</label></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
                        <p>                               content1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
                        <p>                              content2                            </p>

                    </div>
                    <div id="tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
                        <p>                            content3                            </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

---

ok , thanks to CraigF helps I solved 2 problems  with adding 
ids to anchors like id="tabsA-1" and simulating the postback for OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged" with    $("#aspnetForm").submit();

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabsA-1").click(function() {
        $("#<%=RadioButtonCart.ClientID %>").attr("checked", "checked");
        $("#aspnetForm").submit();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

I just have to find a way to select the right tab after postback and my problem is solved.

### thanks to CraigF Again

here is the last piece to select the right tab with help of asp.net

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
        $tabs.tabs('select', '<%= selectedTabIndex %>');

    });
</script>
```

which selectedTabIndex is a public string var in code_behind  and i update its value in page_load. 
 one funny problem was that the .tabs( 'select' , index ) in JQuery **is not zero-based** index of the tab as the official site said and it start from 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQuery to add a click event to the div's. Then simply write a function (Jquery) to reselect the radio button (which will trigger your server side callback for the radiobutton)

Comment: sorry,i am poor at Jquery, can you help more or give some more clue

Comment: Put this in your <head></head> section.

<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#tabs-1").click(function(){ $("#RadioButton1").attr('checked', 'checked'); }); }); </script> This will make the first radio button be selected when they click on the first tab.. you can guess at the rest.

Comment: Don't forget to add groupname to your radio buttons, and add the jquery file to your project.

Comment: You can add $("#form1").submit(); below the $("#Radio.... line. 

Since their aren't any other entities besides <div> tags (for your tabs) you'll have to find or add another item to select, if you don't want the contents to trigger the click event.